# I am using am_map.js from https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/leaflet-map-interactive-layer.html. But my map picker icon not work

Tags: jquery, leaflet

> This is script.
>  I tried icons from cdnjs and image address but no work. Others work fine.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        let lati = Number($('.lat').val());
        let long = Number($('.long').val());

        let map = $("#myMap").am_map({
            // center of the map
            center: [lati, long],
            // map height
            height: '400px',
            background: 'osm',
        });
```

> This is for icon, zoom and points

```
        $("#myMap").am_map('addLayer', {
            // unique name
            name: 'iconLayer',
            // marker point
            points: [lati, long],
            // custom icon HTML
            icon: '<img src="https://imgv3.fotor.com/images/blog-cover-image/part-blurry- 
            image.jpg">',
            // initial zoom level
            zoom: 15,
            // zoom level at which the layer is visible
            limitZoom: 18,
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Now, I knew I forgot to read that comment "// zoom level at which the layer is visible". Haha